# Iteration over a Pandas dataframe using a List Comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can solve this another way; but, I'm interested in understanding exactly why an attempt to iterate over a pandas DataFrame with a list comprehension doesn't work. (Here `a` is a Dataframe)

```
def func(a,seed1,seed2):
    for i in range(0,3):
        # Sum of squares. Results in a series containing 'date' and 'num' 
        sorted1 = ((a-seed1)**2).sum(1)
        sorted2 = ((a-seed2)**2).sum(1)

        # This makes a list out of the dataframe. 
        a = [a.ix[i] for i in a.index if sorted1[i]<sorted2[i]]
        b = [a.ix[i] for i in a.index if sorted1[i]>=sorted2[i]]
        # The above line throws the exception:
        # TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

        # Throw it back into a dataframe...

        a = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['A','B','C'])
        b = pd.DataFrame(b,columns=['A','B','C'])

        # Update the seed.
        seed1 = a.mean()
        seed2 = b.mean()

        print a.head()
        print "I'm computing."
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback and also what are seed1 and seed2?

Comment: @ViktorKerkez use a random DataFrame with three rows and you'll see the above error (seed1/2 are defined above), but OP's bug is more python than pandas. :)

Comment: I was focusing on the wrong thing :) I saw that they are passed in as parameters, but they could be anything... scalars, DataFrames, monkey-birds... Anyhow, your answer is correct.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez ha! You're quite right they could be! I just immediately threw in numbers to see what would happen :)

Comment: I often run my tests with monkey-birds before submitting PRs to pandas :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is after the first line, a is no longer a DataFrame:

```
a = [a.ix[i] for i in a.index if sorted1[i]<sorted2[i]]
b = [a.ix[i] for i in a.index if sorted1[i]>=sorted2[i]]
```

It's a list, and so doesn't have an index attribute (hence the error).

One python trick is to do this in one line (simultaneously define them), that is:

```
a, b = [a.ix[i] for ...], [a.ix[i] for ...]
```

perhaps a better option is to use a different variable name here (e.g. df).

Like you say, there are better ways to do this in pandas, the obvious one is to use a mask:

```
msk = sorted1 < sorted2

seed1 = df[msk].mean()
seed2 = df[~msk].mean()
```

Comment: Yes, it's a list. But my point was, one would think that: here we are building the list, through accessing values from a dataframe...which should be ok(?)...but isn't.

Comment: @MicheleReilly but the first list comprehension is fine. It's the second which trips up (because `a` is no longer the original DataFrame).